# Square of Generic Gorenstein ideal

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, ac.commutative-algebra

Let $S=K[x,y,z]$. Consider $f\in S_{2d}$ a ternary form of even degree and let $I_f$ be the associated Gorenstein ideal, i.e., all polynomials $G$ such that $G(\partial_x,\partial_y,\partial_z)f=0$. Assume that $\dim_K(S/I_f)_i=\min(\dim S_{i},\dim S_{2d-i})$ which is true for generic $f$. Is it true that $(I_f^2)_{2d+2}=S_{2d+2}$? I can prove it for $d=1$ and suspect it to be true for any $d>0$. In the book "Power Sums, Gorenstein Algebras, and Determinantal Loci" by Iarrobino and Kanev I was only able to find Thm.4.1C, which is about non-generic $f$.

Comment: I think it might be true in more than $3$ variables, too. (I only computed a few examples, so I'm not sure, but it seems to be correct.)

Comment: That would be very nice!

Comment: There is an easy weaker statement: $(I_f^k)_{k(d+1)} = S_{k(d+1)}$ for some $k$. To see this, first of all, you have the hypothesis that $S/I_f$ is what Iarrobino calls "compressed", and it implies that $(I_f)_d = 0$. So the minimum degree generators of $I_f$ are in degree $d+1$. Gorenstein symmetry implies the _maximum_ degree generators of $I_f$ are _also_ in degree $d+1$. So $I_f$ is generated purely in degree $d+1$. Next: $I_f$ is $\mathfrak{m}$-primary for the irrelevant (homogeneous maximal) ideal $\mathfrak{m}$. So some $\mathfrak{m}^s \subset I_f$, and it implies my weaker claim.